# What do we do about company name tags? Specifically McAfee?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a [mcafee](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/mcafee) tag with three questions in it. Should this be destroyed and retagged with the relevant product name or are brand-name tags a kind of meta tag that we keep around? It just seems weird that there are only three questions with this tag, which leads me to believe that it may have been shot into orbit at least once before.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds meta tag-ish. It should be burned IMO.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Our [microsoft](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/microsoft), [symantec](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/symantec), [ibm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ibm), [dell](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dell), and [hp](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/hp) tags are in the same boat. The first three on that list I'll argue are meta-tags that need disambiguation. The last two are tricker, since they usually (though not always) are used on hardware-specific problems. A lot of the Dell tags could likely be retagged [dell-poweredge](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dell-poweredge), as would HP and [proliant](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/proliant).

Doing this is going to take one heck of a lot of work. Slow work, lest we flood the front-page with retags.

Once we get the tags cleared, then we can ask to have them blacklisted.

Comment: Don't forget [tag:norton], and think about [tag:procurve] and [tag:juniper] too. [tag:vmware] is empty, but [tag:cisco] seems safe.

Comment: @Andrew: [tag:vmware] is [empty](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1316/can-the-vmware-tag-be-deleted) because we fixed it already.

Comment: @Iain I thought as much.