# Do we need [slow] and [fast] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

<strike>https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/slow</strike>

<strike>https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fast</strike>

Seems like these are quite generic. Many things are slow or fast - they provides no real useful information.

Comment: it should be nuked.

Comment: Tags should be nouns, not adjectives or adverbs.

Comment: As long as we were advocating for nukage of [slow], I figured [fast] should probably be there as well.

Comment: Is 138 for [tag:slow] too many to manually retag over a weekend or two ?

Comment: @Iain Doubtful; I'm pretty sure Programmers has retagged more in less time.

Comment: @Aarthi: The problem with retagging a bunch of questions like this is that it pushes new questions off the front page which is something we like to avoid if possible. A few at a time over a weekend or 2 is ideal.

Comment: @Iain Yeah, that's the biggest problem. Over a weekend would be best, in controlled batches by the hour. What I would do on DIY (when I would edit titles) would redo oldest questions first and newest questions last, that way the newest questions would come back up to the top of the front page when I was done. You may have to take on a similar tack.

Comment: @Aarthi: Erm, I don't think that approach would work when retagging 138/100k questions spread over 2.5 years - they would all just end up on top. The alternative is to [ask the team](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/1323/9517) which doesn't push anything past the front page but I'm not sure if 138 is large enough to ask them.

Comment: @Iain Looks like that's the course you're going to have to take, sorry Iain.

Answer (score 3):

[slow](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/slow) has been burninated. (:

[image: Trogdor]

Answer (score 1):

There are 136 questions tagged [slow](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/slow). Unless anyone objects I will be emailing the team and asking them to delete the tag on Friday 10th Feb 2012.