# The tale of ghost: vmware tag

Tags: bug, tags

Once upon a time in SF land, [there are mass-killing and burnination ritual](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1316/can-the-vmware-tag-be-deleted) of [vmware](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vmware) tag. This mass-killing initiated at [Mar 10, 2011](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1316/can-the-vmware-tag-be-deleted) and [lasted until July 6, 2011](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1316/can-the-vmware-tag-be-deleted#comment2823_1316). The last-killing blow [is done by Jeff Atwood himself](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/1323/218590).

In the present, looks like the [vmware](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vmware) still haunted us. You can see it yourself by

- Visit <s>the graveyard</s> [old question tagged with vmware-*](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vmware-*?page=79&sort=active&pagesize=50).
- Click one of them to bring up the question page, for example: [How do I get the Activation Key in Windows 2003 Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/2490/how-do-i-get-the-activation-key-in-windows-2003-server). You can see there are no [vmware](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vmware) tag in the question.

  > [image]
- Right click **edit button** and select *Open in new tab*.
- Out of nowhere, the [vmware](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vmware) shows up in tag list, replace [vmware-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vmware-server) tag. **The ghost has been revealed himself to us...**

  > [image]

This happened when you edit other questions as well, for example

- [Minimize VMware HD space with multiple snapshots](https://serverfault.com/questions/2640/minimize-vmware-hd-space-with-multiple-snapshots)
- [Where does ESXi decompress files to during install?](https://serverfault.com/questions/112014/where-does-esxi-decompress-files-to-during-install)
- [Kickstarting VMWare ESX 4.1 (Error: No NIC with name bootif)](https://serverfault.com/questions/202645/kickstarting-vmware-esx-4-1-error-no-nic-with-name-bootif)
- [VMWare Lab Manager: What's the difference between Capture to Library and Archive to Library?](https://serverfault.com/questions/222557/vmware-lab-manager-whats-the-difference-between-capture-to-library-and-archive)

I tried to compare the *Tags* data from [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/). And the result is [there are no [vmware] in *Tags* table](http://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/295445). Also, this question - **How do I get the Activation Key in Windows 2003 Server** - [doesn't have [vmware] tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/295388).

So what can we do to kill this *ghost* once and for all?

Comment: Confimed in Chrome 41 and FireFox 36

Comment: I don't understand what was the problem with the vmware tag. The hyper-v tag didn't have any similar mass-killing, I hope nobody is working here for the micro$oft.

Comment: VMware is a company. Hyper-V is a product. There are many products that are prefixed with "VMware <something>." If the user is asking about vSphere or ESXi or View, they should use a more descriptive tag. Having a VMware tag would be akin to having a Microsoft tag, which would be equally useless.

Comment: This is still happening as of today.

Comment: @André, yes. Apparently this bug is only minor. So, perhaps devs has seen this bug but this it has given low-priority because it did not affect the usability of SF

Answer (score 4):

It's just about as killed as killed can get. In fact, [vmware](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vmware) is in our list of blacklisted inputs right along side [amazon](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon). I'm afraid I don't know how those tags are being translated in the edit screen to those banned tagged. This looks like a bug!

Answer (score 4):

*After digging out SEDE once more , I found some explanation why this happened. But still I need SE-dev to finding the **root cause** of this inconsistency.*

### Inconsistency when viewing and editing post

The source of the problem lies in dual data source when you edit and view the post. When you view the post, web page pull data from rendered content (with HTML form) in `Posts` table . But when you edit it, web page pull data from raw content (with Markdown form) in `PostHistory` table. Normally, when you submit the post, [both table updated with same data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48598/260672) (but different forms). Unfortunately sometimes these two data can be out of sync, like this case.

To prove this, I wrote [a query in SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/edit/320853) to compares actual tags saved in `PostTags` table and raw tags recorded in `PostHistory` table. The result almost ~350 questions in Server Fault have this inconsistency. Almost all questions have [vmware](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vmware) in its `PostHistory` entry although it has been converted to another [vmware-wildcard](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vmware-wildcard) tag in `PostTags` table.

My hypotesis is when [Jeff Atwood "manually" converted](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1316/can-the-vmware-tag-be-deleted/1353#1353) [vmware](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vmware) to another [vmware-wildcard](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vmware-wildcard), something wrong happened

1. He forgot to update `PostHistory` table :(
2. He didn't forgot to update `PostHistory` table but in the next-day one of fellow dev rollback the database :(

As for the solution for this kind of "bug": **It can be fixed quickly by SE-developers. Of cource <s>we</s> I can manually edit it, but it'll bump many [vmware](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vmware)questions in frontpage.**

*Additional note:*

*So, this event has happened in the past too. Especially when [image links has been converted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95732/images-manually-uploaded-to-imgur-are-not-displaying/95734#95734) from **i.imgur.com** to **i.stack.imgur.com**. SE developers has been "forced" to [manually baked up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104856/more-and-more-images-go-missing-can-the-cooked-html-be-rebuilt/117011#117011) fresh post bodies so it matched the revision history version.*